# Ajax JQuery Passing Data to POST method

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, jquery

I am a newbie at javascript and jquery and I would like some help if possible.  I searched and tried to make it work, but I think I am missing something simple.

I have the following method in my cs file (CeduleGlobale.aspx.cs)

```
[WebMethod]
     public static void SetSession(string data)
     {
         HttpContext.Current.Session["salesorderno"] = data;
     }
```

I also have a some javascript in my ascx file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SetSession() {

        var request;

        var values = 'fred';
        request = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "CeduleGlobale.aspx/SetSession",
            data: values,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
        });

        request.done(function () {
            alert("Finally it worked!");
        });

        request.fail(function () {
            alert("Sadly it didn't worked!");
        });


    }
</script>
```

The function in the script is called by

```
<dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="cbxHold" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Text="OnHold" ClientSideEvents-CheckedChanged="SetSession">
</dx:ASPxCheckBox>
```

And the result i keep getting is **"Sadly, it didn't work!".**

I know the problem is not with anything relative to the path of the url, because it worked when i passed NULL as data and had the method with no parameters.

The parameters and data is what i tripping me I believe.

Comment: Your options say you are sending JSON data but your `values` are not in valid JSON form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass serialized JSON into the method:

```
var values = JSON.stringify({data:'fred'});
request = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "CeduleGlobale.aspx/SetSession",
    data: values,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Comment: or values = "key1=value1&key2=value2"

Comment: First off all, thanks a lot for all the answers, this community is awesome and very helpful.

I did what you recommended and I am now getting a

Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'JSON' is undefined  error is the Visual Studio debugger.

Answer (score 2):

You are specifying that you are sending JSON, but you don't serialize the value to JSON, so try changing the request to this:

```
request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CeduleGlobale.aspx/SetSession",
        data: JSON.stringify({data: values}), // 'stringify' the values to JSON
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

'fred' is not [**json**](http://www.json.org/) nor object

use object notation :

`{"myattr":"fred"}` //you can also do `{myattr:"fred"}`

and then use `JSON.stringify` which transform it into STRING representation of json object.

Answer (score 1):

The data sent through post should be sent in a {key:value} format
    values={name:'fred'}

Answer (score 1):

The data should be passed into [key:value] pair.